# SSO Login on Crafter CMS

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, crafter-cms

i am crafter user anyway, i want to setting single sign on on my crafter using SAML configuration, I have seen Crafter documentation and follow every step-by-step. Specific related on Identity Provider (IDP) and Service Provider (SP), i encountered issue where I cant find out my crafter entity ID and Attribute Consume Service Endpoint. TBH, i didn't find a way to got that entity ID and Attribute Consume Service Endpoint for many references, could everyone here have experience to looking for "entity ID" and "Attribute Consume Service Endpoint".

I want to know if anyone has the same issue, or if anyone has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

SAML2 is a CrafterCMS enterprise edition feature, if you're on the community (free) edition, it will not work.

If you're on the enterprise edition, you should contact CrafterCMS support.

Comment: is there any other way to apply SSO login on the community edition ?

Comment: No, not in the community edition.